# error 00865! ArcMap geoprocessing. Raster to Polygon

Tags: python, arcmap

I am trying to write a python script to process image files into shapefiles and then to buffer these files with a 5 meter buffer. I first made the script in model builder in arcmap but I am trying to run it for multiple image files, all beginning with the letters LG. I keep getting the error 00865, which states that the input raster (image file) does not exist!! I have checked the folder a million times and it definitely does exist! Here is my code:

```
# Import system modules
import sys, string, os, arcgisscripting

# Create the Geoprocessor object
gp = arcgisscripting.create()

# Load required toolboxes...
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Conversion Tools.tbx")
gp.AddToolbox("C:/Program Files/ArcGIS/ArcToolbox/Toolboxes/Analysis Tools.tbx")

# Script arguments...

folder = "D:\\J04-0083\\IMAGEFILES"
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(folder): # returms root, dirs, and files
    for filename in filenames:
        filename_split = os.path.splitext(filename) # filename and extensionname (extension in [1])
        filename_zero = filename_split[0]

        try:
            first_2_letters = filename_zero[0] + filename_zero[1]
        except:
            first_2_letters = "XX"

        if first_2_letters == "LG":
            Output_polygon_features = "D:\\J04-0083\\ShapeFiles.gdb\\" + "SH_" + filename + ".shp"

            # Process: Raster to Polygon...

            InRaster = filename_zero + ".png"
            gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion(InRaster, Output_polygon_features, "SIMPLIFY", "VALUE") # FILL IN THE CORRECT VALUES!

            Distance__value_or_field_ = "5 Meters"
            Raster_Buffer_shp = "D:\\J04-0083\\ShapeFiles.gdb\\" + "SB_" + filename + ".shp"
            # Process: Buffer...
            gp.Buffer_analysis(Output_polygon_features, Raster_Buffer_shp, Distance__value_or_field_, "FULL", "ROUND", "NONE", "")
```

Does anyone have any idea why it doesn't work? thank you!

Comment: Hi Alice: if you edit your question so that all the code is formatted as code (highlight it and click the 101010 button), it'll be easier to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you're running the script from, but when you call `gp.RasterToPolygon_conversion`, you're only giving it the file *name*, not the full path. If the file's not in the working directory, it won't find it. Try replacing the line:

```
InRaster = filename_zero + ".png"
```

With:

```
InRaster = os.path.join(root, filename_zero + ".png")
```

Comment: thank you so much!! I have a new error now but i will have to take that up with ESRI! Im running the script from pyscripter!

Comment: @Alice: OK, glad it solved that problem, anyway. Quick tip: use the tick symbol on the left to accept my answer (assuming the first problem's completely solved). Besides giving me 'reputation' points, people will see your 'acceptance ratio' when you ask questions in future, and they'll be keener to answer if it's high.